# Concat string in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem. I use SQL Server 2008. I have a table with 2 columns (ID, name). With name's content is Unicode so when I search it to find id, I must write

```
select ID 
from table 
where name = N'ăn'
```

but now I want search content N'ăn' in a variable but I can't concatenate them 
example @var = 'ăn' and I want to concatenate it with N''.

Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: ? How and where does `@var` get defined and populated???

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just declare the variable as `nvarchar()`?

```
declare @var nvarchar(255) = N'ăn';
```

Comment: No @var is dynamic. I must concatenative. I can't

Comment: The point is that where @var is declared, it **must** be declared as `nvarchar`. There is no magic technique you can use that will stuff Unicode strings into a variable defined as `varchar`. It's like trying to put strings into an `INTEGER`. There's no way.